# How to allow access to whole folder with X-Accel-Redirect

Tags: node.js, nginx

i divided my website into a public and a private area. All static files will be served by the nginx. Nodejs only check the credentitals and set the X-Accel-Redirect-Header on success. The problem is, if i set the header like:

```
res.setHeader('X-Accel-Redirect', '/protected/');
```

I get only access to the /protected/index.html not the subfolders with css, images ...
Here is my nginx configuration:

```
location /protected {
  internal;
  access_log off;
  log_not_found off;
  expires max;
}
```

Is it possible to set a whole folder with subfolders in X-Accel-Redirect-Header and not only the index.html?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to set a header directing nginx to the specific resource that you wanted to serve up. For instance:

```
res.setHeader("X-Accel-Redirect", "/protected/images/smile.jpeg");
```

Or whatever is appropriate, based on the request.

Comment: I want to serve a whole website. An index.html with some css, js and images. Its the private area of the site.

Comment: So return an appropriate redirect header based on the requested resource! Right now you're pointing *everything* to the index.

Comment: How a appropriate header look like to point on a folder with all subfolders and not only the index?

Comment: It would have to depend on the request. Details will depend on how your credential checker is implemented, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: So i have to set the X-Accel-Redirect-Header for each file in my protected folder. Their is no way to set the header for a whole folder? I dont want to check if the user is authed on every request. Even on linked files of a html-file. I think that makes the whole site verry slow.

Comment: No - what you are asking for doesn't make sense. If you are running a whole directory through an authorization script, that script will have to run for any request to a resource in that directory, and redirect the request to an appropriate URL for the resource to be served.

Comment: I use nginx to serve static files, because node.js is very bad at this job. But the authentication is done by node.js. If the user is authenticated successfully, he will be redirected to a static folder /protected. I don’t want that the folder /protected is accessible by guest (not authed people) of the websites. Like in that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042316/authentication-across-node-js-and-nginx. So my idea was to use nginx’s XSendfileuse to grant users access to the folder by node.js and nginx will be serving the files.

Comment: @tschiela And how did you fix it? Do I have to get all my requests for say images and css and js authenticated by nodejs then pass it to nginx protected location and then serve the file? Or is there some better alternate to this?